# How to enclose every line in a file in double quotes with sed?

Tags: regex, windows, sed

This is what I tried: `sed -i 's/^.*/"$&"/' myFile.txt`

It put a $ at the beginning of every line.

Comment: have you tried to remove the ampersand?

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say it put a $ at the beginning of each line. Edited. Without the ampersand it does nothing

Comment: both work fine here.. I have no idea what kind of sed you are using

Comment: The `&` does not need the `$`, you're just getting a literal `$`.  Based on your comments I think you have a shell quoting problem, not a `sed` problem.

Comment: This worked: 's/^.*$/\"&\"/'.  

I had to escape the double quotes (but with sed's escape character, not powershell's). I am using sed from GnuWin32. Is this not necessary using other builds of sed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714165/powershell-stripping-double-quotes-from-command-line-arguments

Answer (score 49, accepted):

here it is

```
sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/g'
```

Comment: hmm, this one seems to have no effect at all.

Comment: do i need to escape double quotes in powershell or something?

Comment: Works great on OS X Yosemite.

Comment: For unix/linux beginners, you may want to do something like `cat filename.txt | sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/g'` to feed your input into sed.

Comment: `cat file | <thing>` is a classically incorrect use of `cat`. Use file redirection to pass files into standard input: `sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/g' < filename.txt`.

Answer (score 22):

shorter

```
sed 's/.*/"&"/'
```

without spaces

```
sed 's/ *\(.*\) *$/"\1"/'
```

skip empty lines

```
sed '/^ *$/d;s/.*/"&"/'
```

Answer (score 6):

You almost got it right. Try this slightly modified version:

```
sed 's/^.*$/"&"/g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it without a capture group:

```
sed 's/^\|$/"/g'
```

'^' matches the beginning of the line, and '$' matches the end of the line.

The `|` is an "Alternation", It just means "OR".  It needs to be escaped here[1], so in english `^\|$` means "the beginning or the end of the line".

"Replacing" these characters is fine, it just appends text to the beginning at the end, so we can substitute for `"`, and add the `g` on the end for a global search to match both at once.

[1] Unfortunately, it turns out that | is not part of the POSIX "Basic Regular Expressions" but part of "enhanced" functionality that can be compiled in with the REG_ENHANCED flag, but is not by default on OSX, so you're safer with a proper basic capture group like `s/^\(.*\)$/"\1"/`

Humble pie for me today.

Comment: If you understand the magic of sed, can you explain what this is actually doing?

Comment: I've tried all the answers listed above, nothing works for me but this trick does! Thanks.