# Create new PowerShell process with pipes

Tags: c#, powershell

Running this from CMD produces the correct result:

```
powershell -command "& Get-DiskImage -imagepath C:\\file.vhdx | Get-Disk"
<Here is some stuff regarding VHD>
```

I want to achieve exactly the same running this from C# (there's no way to run it directly, use some PowerShell related .NET stuff, or something else).

My code is the following:

```
static void LaunchCommandLineApp()
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.FileName = "powershell";
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.Arguments = "-command \" & get-diskimage -imagepath C:\\file.vhdx | Get-Disk \"";

    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo)) {
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        var out = exeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

And in "out" I am getting an error:

> Get-Disk : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Number'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.

But exactly the same code works in CMD. If I remove "| Get-Disk" from arguments, I will get correct output in "out" from the [Get-DiskImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-diskimage) cmdlet.

Also, I have tried to play with curly braces, as other answers suggested - error haven't changed.

What shall I put in "startInfo.Arguments", so my output of "Get-DiskImage" will be correctly piped to the next cmdlet?

Comment: What is the output from get-diskimage? The input is looking for the wrong type.

Comment: @ClaytonHarbich just a text with information, if we omit "| Get-Disk"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Process Start needs Arguments with double quotes - they disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339701/c-sharp-process-start-needs-arguments-with-double-quotes-they-disappear)

Comment: That's a good point. Does the command work in a PowerShell terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not actually a problem with the difference between running from the command line and from C#. I created a test VHDX and got the same (error) result whether run from C# or the command line, as shown by the OP.

In both cases, omitting the `| Get-Disk` part showed information about the disk image, which lacked a disk number, which is exactly what `Get-Disk` was complaining about. I suspect the image needs to be mounted for it to have a disk number.

Comment: While my image have mounted - for some reason C# (even plain C system() call) both omitting number. So, C# is not guilty.