# C# quoted string within a quoted string

Tags: c#, json, jq

I'm trying to run JQ on a JSON file, through command line from C# code.
One of the required arguments includes spaces and quotation marks, so it is itself wrapped between quotation mark. However, this argument is formatted from another string which includes quotations marks:

```
var jq =  ".data[] | select(.name==\"mytest\") | .id == \"adxd\"";
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = _exe,
            Arguments = $"-c \"{jq}\" {_settings.JSONFile}",
        };
```

However, the arguments turn out as:

```
-c ".data[] | select(.name=="mytest") | .id == "adxd"" json.json
```

Which of course is wrong.
It should turn out as:

```
-c ".data[] | select(.name==\"mytest\") | .id == \"adxd\"" json.json
```

How can I ensure that the the arguments are decoded correctly with the correct 'levels' of quotation marks?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339701/c-sharp-process-start-needs-arguments-with-double-quotes-they-disappear) should help but I'm trying to find something better.

Comment: You need to escape the \. ==\\\"mytest\\\".

Comment: I can't help but wonder why you opted to use jq for this?

Comment: I'm open for other suggestions @Llama! My modest research brought me to https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Perhaps the .NET library JSON.NET?

Comment: It does not support the functionality I need. I need to be able to run user-provided queries on some json. With JSON.NET the user would have to write actual code as input, rather than simple commands such as in the link I provided. (Unless I missed something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask yourself: "why are there quotes *around* the query argument?"

That's because you're adding an *escaped* quote. The idea here is that writing `\"` in the "code" renders `"` in the output.

You're issue is that you need to do this one layer down. You don't want to *render* the quotes inside the query *in C#*, you want to render the quotes *in the jq.exe application*. So you need to work backwards.

- Inside jp.exe, the value should be `"`.
- This means that whatever we send to it (the command line arguments) need to be escaped: `\"`.
- This means that however we *render* the command line arguments will need to produce `\"`, and because both of those characters require escaping, you do it.

```
jq = jq.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

This says "replace all double quotes in my c# string with a backslash and quote" (essentially, just add a backslash before all quotes).

This turns a c# string rendered as `abc "def" ghi` into `abc \"def\" ghi`, which is the format your command line argument is expecting.