# Plink strips out double quote marks

Tags: powershell, plink

I'm using PowerShell to remotely issue a command on a Linux server. I'm using plink to connect to the server.

However plink strips out double quotes in the commands I want to run. This stops those commands from working.

```
$user = "user"
$password = "password"
$hostname = "host"
$plinkPath = gci -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "plink.exe"} | select -First 1 | foreach{$_.FullName}
& $plinkPath "$User@$hostname" -pw $password "echo" "hello ab`"cdef world"
```

This gives the result

> hello abcdef world

It lost the speech marks in between the 'b' and the 'c'.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I hhink I've figured it, courtesy of *[How do I pass a literal double quote from PowerShell to a native command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314633/how-do-i-pass-a-literal-double-quote-from-powershell-to-a-native-command)*. I am not entirely sure why it works, but it does:

```
$user = "user"
$password = "password"
$hostname = "host"
$plinkPath = gci -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "plink.exe"} | select -First 1 | foreach{$_.FullName}
$command = "hello ab`\`"cdef world"
& $plinkPath "$User@$hostname" -pw $password "echo" ($command -replace '(\\*)"','$1$1\"')
```

[image: Showing it working]