# Using argparse in python to parse an entire JSON

Tags: python, json, parsing, arguments, argparse

I am trying to parse an entire Json in a simple argument using ARGPARSE library, the thing is that it stops suddenly when it hits different elements inside the son, like "-" and " ".

Here is the test code:

```
#parse.py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='JSON_test')
parser.add_argument('-contenido', action='store', dest='CONTENIDO',
                    help='JSON content')
args = parser.parse_args()
C = args.CONTENIDO
print (C)
```

This is an example of the running code

```
python parse.py -contenido """{"desde": "2020-03-01","hasta": "2020-03-31","plantas": [{"id": 6,"nombre": "MDS","inversores": [{"id": "Ingeteam 0237","energa": 2152.8070,"pr": 61.5299,"disponibilidad": 81.1770,"factorPlanta": 15.5313}, {"id": "Ingeteam  0538","energa": 2167.5898,"pr": 61.9315,"disponibilidad": 81.0459,"factorPlanta": 15.6381}, {"id": "Ingeteam 0236","energa": 2168.1885,"pr": 61.9511,"disponibilidad": 80.9856,"factorPlanta": 15.6426}, {"id": "Ingeteam 0563","energa": 2206.8702,"pr": 63.0825,"disponibilidad": 80.9455,"factorPlanta": 15.9219}]"""
```

and finally the error

```
parse.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 0237,energia: 2152.8070,pr: 61.5299,disponibilidad: 81.1770,factorPlanta: 15.5313}, {id: Ingeteam 0538,energia: 2167.5898,pr: 61.9315,disponibilidad: 81.0459,factorPlanta: 15.6381}, {id: Ingeteam 0236,energia: 2168.1885,pr: 61.9511,disponibilidad: 80.9856,factorPlanta: 15.6426}, {id: Ingeteam 0563,energia: 2206.8702,pr: 63.0825,disponibilidad: 80.9455,factorPlanta: 15.9219}]"
```

Our architecture wont let us use a file to parse, so that work around won't work :(.
What can i do? i've read a lot of SOF posts and i will test them tomorrow but i am thinking that they won't suit this specific problem, our json is very large and we need to run it from a single argument.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at `sys.argv[1:]`.  That's what `argparse` looks at.  Your JSON has appear as one long string in that list.  Just how much quoting that requires will depend on your OS and shell.

Comment: what is the command to simulate the CMD content of an argument (-contenido xxxxxxxxx) so that the sys returns xxxxxxxxx?

Comment: It was a CMD / powershell problem in ubuntu it runs. TY all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one single-quote to wrap the command line argument rather than triple-double-quotes. The triple-double-quotes are a Python syntax, not a shell syntax.

```sh
python parse.py -contenido '{"desde": "2020-03-01","hasta": "2020-03-31","plantas": [{"id": 6,"nombre": "MDS","inversores": [{"id": "Ingeteam 0237","energa": 2152.8070,"pr": 61.5299,"disponibilidad": 81.1770,"factorPlanta": 15.5313}, {"id": "Ingeteam  0538","energa": 2167.5898,"pr": 61.9315,"disponibilidad": 81.0459,"factorPlanta": 15.6381}, {"id": "Ingeteam 0236","energa": 2168.1885,"pr": 61.9511,"disponibilidad": 80.9856,"factorPlanta": 15.6426}, {"id": "Ingeteam 0563","energa": 2206.8702,"pr": 63.0825,"disponibilidad": 80.9455,"factorPlanta": 15.9219}]'
```

You may also use one double-quote to wrap the argument, but you'll need to escape each double-quote in the argument.

Comment: with one single quote (') it stops at the first 2020 with single double quote (") it stops at  0237 next to "ingeteam ", with double double quotes ("") it stops again in the first 2020, and with triple double quotes (""") again in 0237. Not sure how it works :/

Comment: @CristobalRencoret: Is there a single quote in the text somewhere?

Comment: @rici there is none, only double Q ( " )

Comment: @CristobalRencoret: OK. I tried it with a single quote and it worked perfectly. It fails with a double single quote, but you claim you used one single quote and as far as I can see, that will work as expected.

Comment: i am using windows 10 anaconda prompt to run it what are you using? @rici

Comment: @cristobal: Bash on Linux. So you're probably running into some wierdness with Windows. It's always good to add details like that to your question.

Comment: [Single quotes apparently don't work in the Windows shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24181667/1566221). Also, if you're using PowerShell, the `run-native` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21334121/1566221) might be useful.