# Why doesn't it work sometimes when using single quotes to surround the command in `python -c [command]` in PowerShell (and in command prompt as well)?

Tags: python, powershell, interpreter, double-quotes, single-quotes

In the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#invoking-the-interpreter) it says:

> A second way of starting the interpreter is `python -c *command* [arg] ...`, which executes the statement(s) in command, analogous to the shell’s `-c` option. Since Python statements often contain spaces or other characters that are special to the shell, it is usually advised to quote *command* in its entirety with single quotes.

So to test this feature, I tried this in PowerShell:

```bsh
> py -c 'print("Hello, World!")'
```

and it shows this error:

```bsh
File "<string>", line 1
    print(Hello, World!)
```

However when I use double quotes instead it works just fine:

```bsh
> py -c "print('Hello, World!')"
```

It seems it only happens for strings. For numbers it works fine. I think the issue here has something to do with using quotes. Why does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is (just like in powershell) single quotes are not interpreted but strings which are strings. this means that python treats the first test `py -c 'print("Hello, World!")'` as all strings but `py -c` expects a command. whereas with double quotes python looks for functions (in your test `print()`) within the string and executes them.

I did not find proof for this on the web but we have the same in powershell as [this blog post describes](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-escape-double-quotes/)

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714165/powershell-stripping-double-quotes-from-command-line-arguments) and [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59681993/13910382)

A short summary:

- It has nothing to do with `python -c`. The fault's all PowerShell's.
- It's a known thing and has being there for years.
- PowerShell does a lot more parsing and escaping on the command you hand it, even if you told it to treat arguments literally. And when calling a native command (in contrast to a PowerShell cmdlet, python in this case), a **single string** `CommandLine` has to be contrived by PowerShell to invoke the underlying Win32 `CreateProcess` function.
- PowerShell's counter-intuitive escaping approach when creating that **single-string** `CommandLine` will strip double quotes from command line arguments, properly escaped or not.

To bypass this feature, quote with single quotes or escape all double quotes with backslashes (`\"`). (Not being a valid escaping syntax in PS, `\"` will be ignored by PowerShell but correctly interpreted by Win32 function `CommandLineToArgvW` when building argv array from the single-string command line that the Windows process gets passed, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw).)