# How to provide a command line argument containing a variable value and quotation marks in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

In PowerShell I want to provide a single command line argument which contains literal quotes *plus* a PowerShell variable value.

I am aware of [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714165/powershell-stripping-double-quotes-from-command-line-arguments), but it doesn't seem to provide a way to enable string interpolation while also having literal quotes unstripped.

A synthetic example:

I want to execute this line of ruby code from the command line: `puts "'u'=<my-user-provided-from-the-shell>"`. (Reminder that this is a synthetic example. I know I can get the username in ruby. I know I can change the code so it doesn't actually need double quotes. For this example I want to execute this exact line of code)

In cmd, I would do this:

```
> ruby -e "puts \"'u'=%USERNAME%\""
```

And it works as expected.

Can I somehow send the exact same argument from powershell?

```
> ruby -e "puts \"`'u`'=$env:USERNAME\""
```

Doesn't work. It fails and produces invalid ruby code. The first quote makes it in, but the `\` from the second goes inside

```
> ruby -e 'puts \"''u''=$env:USERNAME\"'
```

Doesn't fail, but $env:USERNAME is not expanded.

Is it even possible to pass both literal double quotes and a variable value in a single command-line arg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Abra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2164365/abra) who posted [this link](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html) I was able to come up with a solution which works using the subexpression operator:

```
> ruby -e "puts $('\"')'u'=$env:USERNAME$('\"')"
```

Using `$('\"')` looks like the definitive answer to such problems. I don't know why it's not posted in other related questions.