# Problem with AWS iam and JQ filtering roles

Tags: jq, amazon-iam

I'm trying to make a simple filtering script using AWS cli + jq (powershell or cmd in Windows).

```
aws iam list-roles | jq -c '.Roles[].RoleName | select(startswith ("blabla"))'
```

But getting this error:

```
jq: error: AD_/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.Roles[].RoleName | select(startswith (AD_))
jq: 1 compile error
```

But using jqplay.org with same JSON everything works well.
Any thoughts?

thanks!

aws iam list-roles | jq -c '.Roles[].RoleName | select(startswith ("blabla"))'

blabla_rolename_1

Comment: Please share the output of `aws iam list-roles` or the jqplay link to include a [mre].

Comment: `select(startswith (AD_))` is missing the quotes: `select(startswith ("AD_"))`. However that is not the same filter as you state in your question

Comment: Your code block and your error message do not match

Comment: I think this might be helpful (although frustrating): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714165/powershell-stripping-double-quotes-from-command-line-arguments

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be missing a string after the `startswith` function. Try adding a string in quotes after `startswith:`

```
aws iam list-roles | jq -c '.Roles[].RoleName | select(startswith("blabla"))'
```

If you still get an error, you can try running the `jq` command without the `-c` flag to see the full output from `jq`, which might give you more information about the error.

```
aws iam list-roles | jq '.Roles[].RoleName | select(startswith("blabla"))
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Powershell does not support single quotes. Use double quotes and escaped double quotes instead:

```
aws iam list-roles | jq -c ".Roles[].RoleName | select(startswith (\"blabla\"))"
```