# How to pass GitHub secrets as parameters to powershell script

Tags: powershell, github, github-actions

Trying to pass GitHub secrets to powershell script as parameters but getting `***` while executing workflow and it failed:

```yaml
- name: Connecting to shared drive
  env:
    username: ${{secrets.TEST_USERNAME }}
    password: ${{secrets.TEST_PASSWORD }}
  run: ${{ github.workspace }}\Connect-Drive.ps1 ${{ env.username }} ${{ env.password }}
```

Getting this error while executing:

```
The term '***' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable
```

Comment: That is a message from powershell letting you know that parameters were not properly quoted ("escaped"). It writes `***` because secrets in the output are hidden (by GH). Not a powershell expert, but [from what I could gather here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59681993/367456), wrapping the expressions in double or single quotes may work already (is technically not 100% correct for all contents of the expressions, but I have no idea where this is properly documented in some microsoft user-manual, that you can also link online too). `Connect-Drive.ps1 '${{ env.username }}' '${{ env.password }}'`

Comment: Sagar, also check the [new answer from Azeem below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76012144/367456), it looks like a good suggestion to me and also some additional discussion on the quoting /cc @Azeem

Answer (score 4):

Regarding those asterisks `***`, according to [Accessing your secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#accessing-your-secrets):

> **Warning**: GitHub automatically redacts secrets printed to the log ...

So, those secrets are automatically being redacted in logs.

After setting the secrets as environment variables using `env`, you can use those directly with [`$Env:<variable>` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.3#using-the-variable-syntax) instead of using `${{ env.variable }}`:

```yaml
- name: Connecting to shared drive
  env:
    username: ${{ secrets.TEST_USERNAME }}
    password: ${{ secrets.TEST_PASSWORD }}
  run: |
    "$Env:GITHUB_WORKSPACE\Connect-Drive.ps1" "$Env:username" "$Env:password"
```

Need [double quotes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2#double-quoted-strings) around `$Env:<variable>` to be expandable.

See the [Default environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables) for `GITHUB_WORKSPACE`.

If you do use the [`env` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#env-context), make sure to use quotes. In this case, prefer single quotes as the values may contain literals expandable by the shell. See the [Quoting Rules for Powershell 7.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2) for more details as GHA-hosted Windows runners have [Powershell 7.2.10 preinstalled](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/win/Windows2022-Readme.md#powershell-tools).

Answer (score -1):

I think powershell command needs to be surrounded by $(...)

Try this:

```
run: $(${{github.workspace}}\Connect-Drive.ps1 ${{env.username}} ${{env.password}})
```

Comment: Why try this? How does this answer the question? Please add an explanation.

Comment: as powershell script needs to be surrounded by $( )

Comment: Please edit in all the important details to your answer (and - but that's only me - if you could drop a link to a reference of some kind for the rationale, e.g. a link to some docs, would be fine).