# Pass strings containing whitespace to function

Tags: powershell

```
function ed {
    Invoke-Expression "$env:EDITOR $args"
}
ed --option '1 2'  # Any number of parameters here.
```

I expect for `ed` to visit file `1 2`,
but actually it visited `1` and `2`.

Any way to implement what I want?

---

FWIW, the value of my `EDITOR` is

```bash
echo $env:EDITOR
d:/Progs/Emacs/bin/emacsclientw --server-file=d:/Documents/Apps/Emacs/server-auth-dir/server-name.txt --alternate-editor= --create-frame
```

Comment: I'd recommend to read the help [Get-Help about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: it seems like what you wanted was simply `function ed { & $env:EDITOR $args }`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
function EchoStringParameter {
    param (
        [string]$InputString
    )

    Write-Host "$InputString"
}

EchoStringParameter -InputString "1 2"
```

[image]

new update as request

```
function EchoStringParameter {
    echo $args
}

EchoStringParameter --option "1 2"
```

[image]

Comment: I want to pass the arguments without writing `-InputString`. So in your example, the output should be `-InputString` and `1 2`.

Comment: ```function EchoStringParameter {
    param (
        [string]$args
    )

    echo "$args"
}

EchoStringParameter --option "1 2"
```
i used your input, sorry this cannot render well in the comment section.

Comment: Emmm, it outputs only `1 2` in my pwsh. The expected output is `--option` and `1 2`

Comment: sorry it was my misunderstanding. i corrected it. please look at the answer above or in this comment ```function EchoStringParameter {
    echo $args
}

EchoStringParameter --option "1 2"```

Comment: thx.  But this only works for `echo`.  In fact, my original code is `Invoke-Expression "$env:EDITOR $args"`.  I tried `function EchoStringParameter {$env:EDITOR $args}` and pwsh throw an error.

Comment: can you try this
`function EditWithEditor {
    $arguments = $args -join ' '
    Invoke-Expression "$env:EDITOR ""$arguments"""
}

EditWithEditor --option "1 2"`

Comment: `EditWithEditor --option "1 2"` opens file `--option 1 2`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
function f1 {
   Invoke-Expression "echo $args"
   $args
}
```

you will get:

```
PS D:\TEMP> f1 --option a 'b c'
--option
a
b
c
--option
a
b c
PS D:\TEMP>
```

So the use of `Invoke-Expression "echo $args"`, does make you get unwanted output....

---

EDIT: (Because of more info that was given in the question)

When your environment variable also contains parameters which are needed to start your editor, and when you want to pass an unknown number of parameters, you can build the complete statement which is needed to start your editor like this:

```
function ed {
    param(
       [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)][String[]]$Args
       )
    
    $cmd = $env:EDITOR + ' ' + [string]::Join(' ',$Args)
    & Invoke-Expression $cmd
}
```

The variable `cmd` should contain the complete statement that works when you type it at the prompt.

- This works with normal parameters that are not quotes (using single, or double) quotes.
- For correct quoting (when you want to pass two parameters, like `'1 2' '3 4'`), see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70970166/724039 and/or https://stackoverflow.com/a/59681993/724039

NOTE: Please take a note of this warning: "**Take reasonable precautions when using the Invoke-Expression cmdlet in scripts. When using Invoke-Expression to run a command that the user enters, verify that the command is safe to run before running it. In general, it is best to design your script with predefined input options, rather than allowing freeform input.**" (see: [Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.3))

Comment: I just want to pass strings to function separately. It would be nice if `func --option '1 2' "3 4"` behaves as same as what I write in interactive shell: `some-command --option '1 2' "3 4"`