# Converting a list into a single line string in bash

Tags: bash

I have a file that contains a list:

```
line1
line2
line3
.
.
.
```

I want to join everything in a string in bash like so:

```
"line1", "line2", "line3", ...... (no comma at the end)
```

How do I do that?

Edit: This is not a duplicate of [How to join multiple lines of file names into one with custom delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764051) because I am trying to get every item in double quotes while joining.

Comment: Do you want to merge the lines in another file or in a variable in your script?

Comment: Output will go into a second file.

Comment: Yours is still a duplicate; if you need help figuring out how to wrap each line in double quotes before joining, that's a separate question (but also [a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554066/how-to-enclose-every-line-in-a-file-in-double-quotes-with-sed)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say that you file name is test then this will do the trick

```
  while IFS= read -r i; do echo " \"$i\""; done < test | paste -sd "," |sed 's/ //1'
```

Comment: I figured this out but it does not include the quotes.

Comment: now try again, I have updated the answer

Comment: Looks better but still no spaces after commas.

Comment: Use `while read` instead of your `for` loop.

Comment: I have now added the space as well

Comment: `for i in $(cat xyz); do echo " \"$i\""; done |paste -sd ","|sed 's/ //1'`

Comment: You can use @RonakPatel sed to remove the first space that is added

Comment: Can the -ve voter please comment ??

Comment: I didn't vote, but [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work in its current form. Your loop does not iterate over the lines of the file; it iterates over words resulting from the command substitution.

Comment: cat reads each line in the file, and the for loop is over the output of cat, so how is it not iterating . Plus I have verified it to be working

Comment: Try it with an input file that contains more than one word on a single line.

Comment: Also try it with a line like `*`.

Answer (score 7):

For an input file like

```
line1
line2
line3
```

I would use sed and `tr` as follows:

```
$ sed 's/.*/"&"/;$!s/$/, /' infile | tr -d '\n'
"line1", "line2", "line3"
```

The first sed command quotes every line; the second one adds `,`  at the end of every line except the last (the `$!` address: "not the last line").

`tr` then removes all linebreaks.

If you want to do it completely in Bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mapfile -t arr < infile               # Read file into array
arr=("${arr[@]/#/\"}")                # Prepend " to each element
arr=("${arr[@]/%/\"}")                # Append " to each element
IFS=,                                 # Set separator to comma
str="${arr[*]}"                       # Comma separated string
printf '%s\n' "${str//\",\"/\", \"}"  # Insert space after commas
```

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '{ printf "%s\"%s\"", (NR==1?"":", "), $0 } END{ print "" }' file
"line1", "line2", "line3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Building a general solution to most problems of this kind.
Using a general `start`, `middle` and `end` string

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) A solution with only bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

infile="infile"
start='"'
middle='", "'
end='"'

res="$start"                             # start the result with str "$start".
while  IFS=$'\n' read -r line            # for each line in the file.
do     res="${res}${line}${middle}"      # add the line and the middle str.
done   <"$infile"                        # for file "$infile"
res="${res%"$middle"}${end}"             # remove "$middle" on the last line.
printf '%s\n' "${res}"                   # print result.
```

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk)
And a solution for larger files with awk:

```
#!/bin/bash

infile="infile"
start='"'
middle='", "'
end='"'

awk -vs="$start" -vm="$middle" -ve="$end" '
BEGIN{printf("%s",s)}
{
if(ll){printf("%s%s",ll,m)}
ll=$0
}
END{printf("%s%s%s",ll,e,"\n")}
' "$infile"
```